# When connected via VPN with Cisco to my University I am non online

Tags: wireless-networking, cisco-anyconnect

I am home and I have 2 laptops. Both have the most recent Cisco Anyconnect version. They are both connected via wifi to the same network and they both have Windows 10. On one laptop when I connect to my University Using Cisco Anyconnect, everything works. On the other laptop, when I connect to my University Using Cisco Anyconnect, I cannot go online. My wifi says "connected, secured" but I cannot browse. This started a few weeks ago, before everything was fine, no idea how this happened. Any suggestion on how I could run some commands on both laptops to understand the differences and figure out the issue? What I tried: I reinstalled Cisco in the laptop having issues but nothing changed. Rebooted multiple times.

Comment: Is your wireless for the problem computer on the same subnet as the good computer?  If not, then by chance, is the problem computer the the same subnet as the University?  That could cause what you see.

Comment: Mmm I know nothing about subnet. I am home, and I have a basic At&t router. They are both connected to the same at&t wireless network. Everything worked until few weeks ago.

Comment: If you have both machines on one network , it is probably not a subnet issue. I will keep looking around. I use NCP secure entry on Cisco gear so I have a familiarity with this.  You might also ask the University Support people.

Comment: I asked they dont know whats going on. Any suggestions of things I could test on the two pc to see why is not connected in one but it is in the other?

Comment: As a note: I can ping 1.1.1.1 but I am not online on any browser

Comment: I see people online speaking about split DNS, no idea how to do it. Is it a option on Cisco anyconnect? Or a Windows 10 setup?

Comment: I cannot tell you about split DNS in CIsco as that is not common in my VPN apps.